# Cant get string data from post request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i made a Servlet which should receive a string contains XML data in a post request, the string is sent like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ocsRequest>
   <requestType>2015</requestType>
   <serviceNode>xx</serviceNode>
   <sequenceNo>1463918615065</sequenceNo>
   <callingParty>9656500000</callingParty>
   <serviceType>P-aRX2zvEwMY2</serviceType>
   <serviceId>S-NgY2zvxxxx</serviceId>
   <bearerId>SMS</bearerId>
   <chargeAmount>60.0</chargeAmount>
   <planId>Fit_DuSxxxx</planId>
   <asyncFlag>N</asyncFlag>
   <renewalFlag>-1</renewalFlag>
   <bundleType>N</bundleType>
   <serviceUsage>-1</serviceUsage>
   <promoId>-1</promoId>
   <subscriptionFlag>S</subscriptionFlag>
   <optionalParameter1>msgText#Follow this link, or try from PC. http://localhost:8084/Notification/contents/ddd.mp3</optionalParameter1>
   <optionalParameter2>reqSource#1319</optionalParameter2>
   <optionalParameter3>languageId#en</optionalParameter3>
   <optionalParameter4>-1</optionalParameter4>
   <optionalParameter5>-1</optionalParameter5>
</ocsRequest>
```

but when i am trying receiving it like this

```
String xmlContent = request.getParameter("xmlContent");
out.write(xmlContent);
```

it gives me

```
<ocsRequest>
    <requestType>2015</requestType>
    <serviceNode>FITxxx</serviceNode>
    <sequenceNo>1463918615065</sequenceNo>
    <callingParty>96565682860</callingParty>
    <serviceType>P-aRX2zvEwMY2</serviceType>
    <serviceId>S-NgY2zvEwMY2Du</serviceId>
    <bearerId>SMS</bearerId>
    <chargeAmount>60.0</chargeAmount>
    <planId>Fit_DuSudai_60</planId>
    <asyncFlag>N</asyncFlag>
    <renewalFlag>-1</renewalFlag>
    <bundleType>N</bundleType>
    <serviceUsage>-1</serviceUsage>
    <promoId>-1</promoId>
    <subscriptionFlag>S</subscriptionFlag>
    <optionalParameter1>msgText
```

the string is not completed it is missing some part after msgText

i also tried to send the string in a get request but have the same problem

Comment: Can you try with `out.flush();` after `out.write(xmlContent);` ?

Comment: it gives me the same uncompleted response!

Comment: The `#` is a special character in URLs representing start of fragment identifier. You likely need to tell the client that it has to URL-encode the parameter value before sending it to the server. Or, if you're responsible for the client code yourself, fix it yourself accordingly.